# Codenameone AutoCompleteTextField scrolling on Android causes select

Tags: codenameone

When using AutoCompleteTextField on android it selects and closes the popup when trying to scroll a long list.  The code is based on the sample code provided by codenameone.  The iOS and Simulator version work fine though.  I'll have to grab a few different version os android devices to see if the issue is with that.

```
DefaultListModel<String> list_SearchBoxResults = new DefaultListModel<>();

    SearchBox = new AutoCompleteTextField(list_SearchBoxResults) {
        @Override
        protected boolean filter(String text) {
            if(text.length() == 0) 
            {
                return false;
            }

            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
            for(class_Parts part:Parent.list_Inventory)
            {
                if( part.FullText.contains(text.toLowerCase()) ) 
                {
                    if(part.OnHandQuantity > 0)
                    {
                        results.add(part.SKU + " - " + part.PartName + " Avail:" + Double.toString(part.OnHandQuantity) );
                    }
                }

            }

            if(results.isEmpty()) 
            {
                list_SearchBoxResults.removeAll();
                return false;
            }

            list_SearchBoxResults.removeAll();
            for(String s:results) 
            {
                list_SearchBoxResults.addItem(s);
            }
            return true;
        }

    };
    SearchBox.setHint("Search");
    SearchBox.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);
```

Comment: How do you add the search box to the form and in what layout? Does the virtual keyboard behave differently when you scroll on Android (e.g. fold)

Comment: So far I cannot reproduce this issue.  Please file an issue in the CN1 issue tracker and include a self-contained test case that I can build.  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new

Comment: It's a few different issues.  So when the user scrolls and slides their finger too far and they go above or below the popup box the window closes.  And I discovered on iOS it works fine in Portrait mode but in Landscape mode it selects the item where you touch to scroll.   I'll make an empty app with only the one field and test on both.

Comment: I switched the app to use a TextField and a Picker.  The functionality is much more predictable across the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this to GitHub and the issue was correct https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2737#event-2203285379